# Ignoring exception in view discord.py , i dont really get it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-interactions

**Full error :**

```
[ERROR] discord.ui.view: Ignoring exception in view <MySelect timeout=None children=1> for item <Select placeholder='Choose an option' min_values=1 max_values=1 disabled=False options=[<SelectOption label='Introduction' value='1' description=None emoji=None default=False>, <SelectOption label='Starting' value='2' description=None emoji=None default=False>]> (view.py:412)
```

**My Piece of code:**

```py
class MySelect(View):
    @discord.ui.select(
            placeholder="Choose an option",
            options=[
                discord.SelectOption(label="Introduction", value="1"),
                discord.SelectOption(label="Starting",value="2")
                ]
            )
    
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
        select.disabled=True
        if select.values[0] == "1":
            embed1=discord.Embed(
            title=f"Welcome to Will of Steel",
            description=f"""xxxxxxxxxx""", color=0x2F3136)
            embed1.set_thumbnail(url="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed1)

        if select.values[0] == "2":
            #full embed is here....
            embed2.add_field(name=f"Step 1", value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", inline=True)
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed2)

@command_tree.command()
async def dummyhelp(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    """Dummy help command"""
    await interaction.response.defer(thinking=True)

    embed1=discord.Embed(
            title=f"Welcome to Will of Steel",
            description=f"""blablabllablablablal""", color=0x2F3136)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url="xxxx")
      
    view=MySelect(timeout=None)


    await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed1, view=view)
```

Actually, I don't really grasp what the error means, and I'm quite new to all these new interactions with discord API so any example would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20select#id2) the order of the `select` and `interaction` parameters of the callback is opposite of yours.

Comment: yes, true. however it didn't change anything yet.